# How To Force User To Enter Only Digits In input type='tel' Wp Contact Form 7 Plugin Just Like Gravity Form plugin

Tags: wordpress

I Just Want To Force User To Enter Only Digits In telephone field of contact form 7 plugin not other characters just like gravity form plugin.Is It Possible?
I Have Tried Below Link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-phone-mask-field/
But I Got Output Like This:
[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxS8b.png)

my Contact Form 7 Looks Like Below:
[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Y8p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form 7 has a validation system for the telephone numbers, you could use the following code to verify the telephone number the user is writing:

```
[number* your-telephone minlength:10 maxlength:140 placeholder "Telephone number"]
```

also you can use this documentation [here for more information](https://contactform7.com/number-fields/)

hope this help.

Comment: i need solution for wp contact form 7 plugin only

Comment: I have edited the code for you, this code will work with Form 7